# How to access Django ForeignKey model field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two django models

model A

```
class A(models.Model):
    aname = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='name')
```

and model B

```
class B(models.Model):
    bname = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='name')
    mod = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='a_b',null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The serializer for model B is

```
class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
mod= ASerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = B
    fields = (','id','bname','mod.aname')
```

I want the *aname* field of model A to be accessed with the serializer of model B. Using mod.aname doesn't work. It says

> Field name `mod.aname` is not valid for model `B`.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one? using parameter `source` inside `serializers.CharField`:

```
class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mod = serializers.CharField(
        source='mod.aname',
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ('id','bname','mod')
```

Comment: it works. thanks. please not that i have changed the model Hotel to B and HotelSerializer to Bserializer for better understanding. It will be helpful for someone if u ll change your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use two underscores when referencing fields of related models as a string, like `'mod__aname'`.

```
class HotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mod= ASerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = ('id','bname','mod__aname')
```

This should work if `ASerializer` looks something like this:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: doesn't work. shows mod__aname is not a valid model for B

Comment: I see you've changed the names of your models. It's hard for me to help debug stuff if I don't actually know what you have typed out. As is, I can't tell if `B` is actually called `Hotel` and you changed it for the post or if you've made a mistake in your code by leaving in `Hotel`.

Comment: I have changed Hotel to B , HotelSerializer to Bserializer for better convenience. no other change. I hope that doesn't have any effect on your answer.